# install4j java.lang.NullPointerException when clicking "Browse" button in installation location screen

Tags: nullpointerexception, install4j

I made a install package with install4j version 5.1.2.

In the process of installing the package, on installation location screen first I clear the text field of "Destination directory", then I click the browse button and want to select a whole new installation location, NO response from this mouse event, at the same time there is a error.log file created.

The content of the error.log is like below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.components.DirectorySelector.doBrowse(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.components.DirectorySelector.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.components.DirectorySelector$1.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
```

Is there any possible that something is wrong with install4j? Or any other reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in install4j that was fixed in 5.1.3.

Comment: Everything is OK when I use version 5.1.3. Thank you, Ingo.